# Rails 3 ActionMailer Google Apps: Timeout::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, gmail, actionmailer

I've been trying to fix this for way too many hours.  I looked at Railscast, official Rails Guides, lots of blog posts and none of them help.

I'm trying to send email from my Rails 3 app using ActionMailer 2.2.5 via my Google Apps account.  I verified the username and password.  I can see on the console the message to be sent.  I'm getting a **Timeout::Error** from the *deliver* call in my controller.

Can someone shed any light on this?

Here's the code:

```
# config/environments/development.rb
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :tls => true,
  :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :port => "587",
  :authentication => :plain,                                                                                                                     
  :domain => 'test.com',
  :user_name => 'user@test.com',
  :password => 'mypass'
}

# app/mailers/test_mailer.rb
class PostMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "no-reply@test.com"

 def activate_email( post )
   @post = post
   mail( :to => post.email,
         :subject => "Testing" )
   end
 end

# app/controllers/test_controller.rb
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.new( params[:post] )
    TestMailer.activate_email( @post ).deliver
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try two things.  First off make port a number instead of a string:

```
:port => 587
```

Also in my code I have the following line before the actionmailer config:

```
Net::SMTP.enable_tls(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
```

Is there any reason that you are using an old version of actionmailer with rails 3?  I would recommend using the version of actionmailer that corresponds to your rails version.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Turns out I was behind a stupid firewall, everything works now.

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out!